# Setting up Themeforest HTML template with Vue and Laravel. Loading JS files on router.push not working

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I am setting up my first every frontend website with Vue and Larvavel. I have bought html/css/javascript based template on Themeforest.

Setup vue and vue router with laravel and all seems working find here is my app.js files look like

```
require('./bootstrap');
import $ from 'jquery';

window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import routes from './router';
import slider from "./components/slider/index.vue";
import insideheader from "./components/slider/innerheader.vue";


Vue.use(VueRouter);

import App from './components/App.vue';
Vue.component('slider', slider );
Vue.component('insideheader', insideheader );

const router = new VueRouter({
mode: 'history',
routes,

});

Vue.router = router

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {

   },

    router: router,
    render: t => t(App),

 });


  require('./js/vendor/jquery-library.js')
  require('./js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js')
  require('./js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js')
  require('./js/owl.carousel.min.js')
  require('./js/jquery.svgInject.js')
  require('./js/isotope.pkgd.js')
  require( './js/chartsloader.js')
  require('./js/parallax.js')
  require('./js/countTo.js')
  window._ = require('./js/appear.js')
  // require('./js/gmap3.js');
  require('./js/main.js')
```

That's what my App.vue looks like

```
import Home from "./../components/home.vue";
import About from "./../components/about.vue";

const router = [

  { path: '/', component: Home, name: 'home' },
  { path: '/home', component: Home, name: 'home' },
  { path: '/about', component: About, name: 'about' },  
]

export default router;
```

When I load my home or about using direct link such as

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/home
http://127.0.0.1:8000/about
```

It works fine but if I use $router.push to change url and load another vue file

```
this.$router.push(link);
```

Page doesnt appear properly either css or js files aren't functioning properly but I do not get any error in my console about it so not sure what to fix. My guess is js files coz page classes are loading properly it's the jquery based function doesn't seem to be doing their job.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for your response in advance.

```
<template>
    <span>


    <slider></slider>
    <!--************************************
            Main Start
    *************************************-->
    <main id="tg-main" class="tg-main tg-haslayout">


        <!--************************************
                Statistics Start
        *************************************-->
        <section class="tg-haslayout tg-parallax-window" data-appear-top-offset="600" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="images/parallax/bgparallax-01.jpg">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="tg-statistics">
                        <div class="tg-statistic tg-goals">
                            <span class="icon-Icon1 tg-icon"></span>
                            <div class="tg-namecount">
                                <h2><span class="tg-statistic-count" data-from="0" data-to="1900" data-speed="8000" data-refresh-interval="50">1900+</span></h2>
                                <h3>Happy customers</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tg-statistic tg-activeplayers">
                            <span class="icon-Icon2 tg-icon"></span>
                            <div class="tg-namecount">
                                <h2><span class="tg-statistic-count" data-from="0" data-to="967" data-speed="8000" data-refresh-interval="50">967</span></h2>
                                <h3>Successful Deals</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tg-statistic tg-activeteams">
                            <span class="icon-Icon3 tg-icon"></span>
                            <div class="tg-namecount">
                                <h2><span class="tg-statistic-count" data-from="0" data-to="1208" data-speed="8000" data-refresh-interval="50">1208</span></h2>
                                <h3>awards earned</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!--************************************
                Statistics End
        *************************************-->


    </main>
    <!--************************************
            Main End
    *************************************-->

</span>
</template>
<script>

export default {

    data() {

        return {

            test: 'test1'

        }

     },



    methods: {


    },

    created() {



    },

    mounted() {

    },


}
</script>
```

About.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="tg-wrapper" class="tg-wrapper tg-haslayout">


    <insideheader></insideheader>
    <!--************************************
            Main Start
    *************************************-->
    <main id="tg-main" class="tg-main tg-haslayout">

        <!--************************************
                Video Why Choose Us? Start
        *************************************-->
        <section class="tg-bglight tg-haslayout">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="tg-videosection">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="images/img-01.jpg" alt="image description">
                            <figcaption>
                                <a class="tg-btnplay" href="#"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
                                <h2>our business Introduction</h2>
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="tg-whychooseus">
                    <div class="tg-sectionhead">
                        <div class="tg-sectiontitle">
                            <h2>best in town</h2>
                            <h3>why choose us?</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tg-description">
                            <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore iqua Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tg-ourskill" class="tg-ourskill tg-skillgroup">
                        <div class="tg-skill">
                            <h4>FINANCIAL ANALYSIS</h4>
                            <div class="tg-skillholder" data-percent="95%">
                                <div class="tg-skillbar">
                                    <h5>95%</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tg-skill tg-active">
                            <h4>INVESTMENTS</h4>
                            <div class="tg-skillholder" data-percent="80%">
                                <div class="tg-skillbar">
                                    <h5>80%</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tg-skill">
                            <h4>FINANCIAL PLANNER</h4>
                            <div class="tg-skillholder" data-percent="50%">
                                <div class="tg-skillbar">
                                    <h5>50%</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tg-skill">
                            <h4>BUSINESS SUPPORT</h4>
                            <div class="tg-skillholder" data-percent="90%">
                                <div class="tg-skillbar">
                                    <h5>90%</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!--************************************
                Video Why Choose Us? End
        *************************************-->
        <!--************************************
                Perfessional Team Start
        *************************************-->
        <section class="tg-main-section tg-haslayout">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="tg-sectionhead">
                            <div class="tg-sectiontitle">
                                <h2>Meet our</h2>
                                <h3>Professional Team</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tg-description">
                                <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tg-teamslider" class="tg-teamslider tg-teammembers">
                        <div class="item tg-member">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="images/team/img-01.jpg" alt="image description">
                                <figcaption>
                                    <ul class="tg-socialprofilelinks">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="tg-memberinfo">
                                <div class="tg-membername">
                                    <h4><a href="#">Dwight Billick</a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tg-memberdesignation">
                                    <span><a href="#">Financial Planner</a></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item tg-member">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="images/team/img-02.jpg" alt="image description">
                                <figcaption>
                                    <ul class="tg-socialprofilelinks">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="tg-memberinfo">
                                <div class="tg-membername">
                                    <h4><a href="#">Leonia Murch</a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tg-memberdesignation">
                                    <span><a href="#">Financial Planner</a></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item tg-member">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="images/team/img-03.jpg" alt="image description">
                                <figcaption>
                                    <ul class="tg-socialprofilelinks">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="tg-memberinfo">
                                <div class="tg-membername">
                                    <h4><a href="#">Milford Mcwilliam</a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tg-memberdesignation">
                                    <span><a href="#">Financial Planner</a></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item tg-member">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="images/team/img-04.jpg" alt="image description">
                                <figcaption>
                                    <ul class="tg-socialprofilelinks">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="tg-memberinfo">
                                <div class="tg-membername">
                                    <h4><a href="#">Jessenia Ly</a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tg-memberdesignation">
                                    <span><a href="#">Financial Planner</a></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item tg-member">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="images/team/img-01.jpg" alt="image description">
                                <figcaption>
                                    <ul class="tg-socialprofilelinks">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="tg-memberinfo">
                                <div class="tg-membername">
                                    <h4><a href="#">Dwight Billick</a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tg-memberdesignation">
                                    <span><a href="#">Financial Planner</a></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item tg-member">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="images/team/img-02.jpg" alt="image description">
                                <figcaption>
                                    <ul class="tg-socialprofilelinks">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="tg-memberinfo">
                                <div class="tg-membername">
                                    <h4><a href="#">Leonia Murch</a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tg-memberdesignation">
                                    <span><a href="#">Financial Planner</a></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item tg-member">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="images/team/img-01.jpg" alt="image description">
                                <figcaption>
                                    <ul class="tg-socialprofilelinks">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="tg-memberinfo">
                                <div class="tg-membername">
                                    <h4><a href="#">Dwight Billick</a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tg-memberdesignation">
                                    <span><a href="#">Financial Planner</a></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item tg-member">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="images/team/img-02.jpg" alt="image description">
                                <figcaption>
                                    <ul class="tg-socialprofilelinks">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="tg-memberinfo">
                                <div class="tg-membername">
                                    <h4><a href="#">Leonia Murch</a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tg-memberdesignation">
                                    <span><a href="#">Financial Planner</a></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item tg-member">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="images/team/img-03.jpg" alt="image description">
                                <figcaption>
                                    <ul class="tg-socialprofilelinks">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="tg-memberinfo">
                                <div class="tg-membername">
                                    <h4><a href="#">Milford Mcwilliam</a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tg-memberdesignation">
                                    <span><a href="#">Financial Planner</a></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item tg-member">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="images/team/img-04.jpg" alt="image description">
                                <figcaption>
                                    <ul class="tg-socialprofilelinks">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="tg-memberinfo">
                                <div class="tg-membername">
                                    <h4><a href="#">Jessenia Ly</a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tg-memberdesignation">
                                    <span><a href="#">Financial Planner</a></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!--************************************
                Perfessional Team End
        *************************************-->

    </main>
    <!--************************************
            Main End
    *************************************-->

</div>
</template>
<script>



export default {

data() {

    return {

        test: 'test2'

    }

},



methods: {

    autoComplete(){

        alert('hit');

    }


},

created() {



},
mounted() {

    // this.$root.$on('UpdateWaiting', this.waitingapproval)

},


}
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you assigning multiple different files to `window._`?

Comment: @RossWilson oh sorry, I was trying something they aren't actually assigned to windows._ changing my question

Comment: Can you add you `home.vue` and `about.vue` files and also what `console.log(link);` outputs?

Comment: @RossWilson home.vue and about.vue contains the html of both pages. You want me to upload full pages or just script? console.log(link) giving 'home' and 'about'

Comment: The full pages please :)

Comment: @RossWilson I cannot upload the full pages because stackoverflow didn't let me. However I have removed some html from pages and added them up there.

Comment: @RossWilson any ideas? still stuck... tried almost anything. I noticed if I reload page it works fine. If I change $route and come back to it it's all distorted :(

Comment: I could be wrong and I'm not sure what it would be exactly but the only thing I can think of at this point is that something is getting initialised on page load that isn't getting applied when the markup changes.

Comment: @RossWilson hmmm. I tried all sorts of way but nothing worknig so far. How about I push it to git and share with you. Would you be able to help me with that?

Comment: I can definitely have a look.

Comment: @RossWilson ok I am working to push it to git. Thanks for being extremely helpful  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179675/discussion-between-zee-and-ross-wilson).

Comment: @RossWilson you getting my messages on chat?

Comment: your question helped me now. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to jQuery not loading...

As you know vue router will not reload the page but will change the URL in browser and update the virtual DOM. In that case the DOM is updated but jQuery is not called.

I am not very much expert in vue but I think either you should move the following statements in a component and call it in home and about component or in the mounted function of these components.

```
require('./js/vendor/jquery-library.js')
require('./js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js')
require('./js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js')
require('./js/owl.carousel.min.js')
require('./js/jquery.svgInject.js')
require('./js/isotope.pkgd.js')
require( './js/chartsloader.js')
require('./js/parallax.js')
require('./js/countTo.js')
window._ = require('./js/appear.js')
// require('./js/gmap3.js');
require('./js/main.js')
```

Comment: I have tried that. I made a separate file called alljs.vue and load that as component and then call them in home and about. It worked on first load but on changing pages it doesn’t work :(

Comment: I can share my git repository with you if you wish

Comment: I think this would be breaking because the new component alljs.vue is loading always you are changing to home component and about component....  This should be handled to call only once i.e. the first time home or about  component load. Also I think you should only call main.js to load as I think that is the only file initializing jQuery plugins

Comment: I’ll give it a go but I think I already tried that. But I’ll try again. What do you mean by first time load? How do I do that?

Comment: To set if jQuery functions are loaded for a particular component home or about you can add a prop say isJqueryLoaded initially set to 0 which can be set dynamically when the alljs.vue file is loaded for that component to say 1 and we can call alljs.vue component for home or about component only if the prop isJqueryLoded is 0... making to call only once

Comment: I haven’t used prop before now you gave me another task to learn them :-) Thanks

Comment: Hey I am not a vue expert but you need check between prop and state basically as to what should be used. I think best will be to use state...